# IcCube reporting V8 - How to adjust collapsible filters?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

In V7 reporting, collapsible filters had options to setup their width in px and their height in either px or number of rows. Also there was an option to collapse on mouse leave.

[image]

Do these parameters exist as well in new V8 and I just did not find them ?

Answer (score 1):

V8 does not support collapse on mouse leave.

The options about styling are moved into the theme API, see https://github.com/ic3-software/ic3-demo-plugin-theme and https://livedemo.iccube.com/icCube/report/help?ic3topic=api.plugin.Theme&ic3locale=en_US.

E.g., the code below shows where to set the tree item height (using the git example from above).

```js
/**
 * Input of createMuiTheme( {...} )
 */
export const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {

    ic3: {
        id: themeId,
        caption: "ic3 Demo Theme",

        cssClass: 'ic3-demo-theme',
        
        treeFilter: {
            itemHeight: 38
        },
        //...
    },
    //...
}
```

For the next release, we're going to add an option in the theme for the popup width and height.

Comment: So the width & height will be adjustable for every single widget inside a report ? Right ?

Comment: I was thinking more about a general setting for all tree-widgets. Is that something you could work with?

Comment: That's what I feared, Our use is today (V7) defined widget by widget, some will have only 2 or 4 rows, some will be 150, 300, or 500px large, I'm here talking about the collapsible part. "Header" part is almost always the same. So, I don't see how we can manage this using the theme. Furthermore, it's not only TreeFilter related, but all the widgets that allow collapsible part.